# Count No of rows multi query

Tags: php, mysql

How I count the no of rows returned from this below query

```
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY time) AS t1 GROUP BY fbid ORDER BY time
```

Comment: What database API are you using? `mysql`, `mysqli`, or `PDO`?

Comment: Have you tried anything, anything at all?

Comment: `mysqli_num_rows()` or `PDOStatement::rowCount()`

Comment: @Barmar : using `count(1)` would also solve if used in sql...right?

Comment: @barmar I am using mysqli

Comment: Consider posting an answer or closing the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM
 ( SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY time) AS t1
 GROUP BY fbid
 ORDER BY time
INNER JOIN
 SELECT COUNT(fbid) AS 'row count'
 FROM
 ( SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY time) AS t2
 GROUP BY fbid
 ORDER BY time
ON (t1.fbid=t2.fbid)
```